# Reading data value from mysql database through queries

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a login and registration php system on my website. It works perfectly fine. However I would like to add another column to the database. This is balance. I want to display the users 'balance' when they log in on the website.
I have tried to select the balance data value through using this:

```
<?php
$balance = mysqli_query("SELECT balance FROM users WHERE username='$username' 
AND password='$password'");
echo $balance
?>
```

I am new to php programming therefore I am unsure what is wrong with this piece of code.
The sql database looks as follows:

```
id    username    email    password    balance
test  test        test     test        test
```

I would assume from my code that the variable $balance would be set from the value received, that if the username and password entered on the login page is the found on the database. The balance in relation to this will be printed. 
This is included in my html part of the web page to display the value of balance:

```
<a href="#">Balance: <?php echo $balance ?><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
```

When testing the website I get the following error

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in D:\Windows\xampp\htdocs\TESTSITE\FrontPage.php on line 3

I have tried to figure this out through research but I can't find a solution. Any solutions are welcome as I have reached a stop in development.

In addition I know this is extremely insecure and I shall be ensuring the code is much more secure when the website goes live. I am merely testing at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You have 4 issues.

1. You need to hash your users passwords, storing plaintext passwords is bad practice.
2. You need to parameterize your query because without that you are open to SQL injections, and depending on the user's username/password could break your query inadvertently.
3. The `query` function expects parameter 1 to be the connection object.
4. The `query` function returns a result object which needs to be fetched.

Here's an updated version that should function. This assumes `$conn` is your connection.

```
<?php
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT balance FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $user, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $balance);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
echo $balance;
?>
```

This doesn't account for the hashing. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php. You will need to hash all values in your DB currently.

Comment: Tried your code got errors:
Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in D:\Windows\xampp\htdocs\TEST\FrontPage.php on line 4
Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in D:\Windows\xampp\htdocs\TEST\FrontPage.php on line 5
Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in D:\Windows\xampp\htdocs\TEST\FrontPage.php on line 6
Warning: mysqli_stmt_fetch() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in D:\Windows\xampp\htdocs\TEST\FrontPage.php on line 7

Comment: @Jamie The `prepare` failed to use the error reporting on that to see why. Did you change `$conn` to your actual mysqli connection variable? Something like `printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));` should give you something back, see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php for more information.

Comment: I changed the $conn to $db as that is the connection variable. I also tried to add printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn)); but nothing changed.

Comment: Do it as an if around the `prepare`.

Comment: Sorry I dont quite understand

Answer (score -2):

1. If you are using mysqli you must set like this :

   ```
   $balance = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT balance FROM users WHERE username='$username'
   ```

   AND password='$password'"); // $connection is your configuration for connection.
2. You must get value from input, like this :

   ```
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $pass = $_POST['pass'];
   ```

Then get boolean from query ,like this :

```
if($balance) echo 'success' else echo 'wrong';
```

Comment: Your first point is completely incorrect syntax wise. And your second point completely ignores what im asking of. I want the data value to be displayed without the user having to enter it. The data value is already set in the sql database.

Comment: I just give an example for my first statement, and second statement is for your problem without explained. To display data you must loop your query first before echo :-p